# Cannot modify header information and invalid argument. But argument seems ok

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following errors:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/site/www.mysite.com/admin/categories.php on line 324
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/site/www.mysite.com/admin/categories.php:324)
>   in /home/site/www.mysite.com/admin/includes/functions/general.php on
>   line 35

And I am not sure exactly what to look for.

line 324 looks like this:

```
    foreach ($icons_id as $iconid) {
                     tep_db_query("insert into " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_ICONS . " (products_id, icons_id) values ('" . (int)$products_id . "', '" . (int)$iconid . "')");

    }
```

and line 35 looks like this:

```
 header('Location: ' . $url);
```

I think this has more to do with the invalid argument but I am not sure why it is invalid?

Comment: The failed `header` call is indeed caused by the previous warning because you cannot modify headers after they're already sent. Since the invalid argument causes warning output, the headers are already sent by the time you try to modify headers. What is the value of `$icons_id`? Can you do a print_r to debug to make sure it's an array?

Comment: What is the value of `$icons_id`? The error implies that it's not an array.

Comment: Ok good to know. So I will look into why it is invalid

Comment: check `var_dump($icons_id)`

Comment: first check if it is array .  `if(is_array($icons_id ))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in my comment, the header call fails because of the previous warning, so you'll need to solve that first. The warning indicates `$icons_id` is not an array. You can add a safeguard like so:

```
 if (is_array($icons_id)){
     foreach ($icons_id as $iconid) {
         tep_db_query("insert into " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_ICONS . " (products_id, icons_id) values ('" . (int)$products_id . "', '" . (int)$iconid . "')");
    }
}
```

This will prevent that warning, but you'll still need to figure out what's going on with `$icons_id` and why it's not an array if you expect it to be.

Comment: Ya I ended up doing !empty($icons_id) as it was when it was empty that was causing the error. Seems to work the same as this would I would think. Is there any difference between empty and isarray?

Comment: `if(is_array($icons_id ))`

Comment: what about header issue ?

Comment: It is resolved by resolving the error. See my comment on the above post.